# virsh destroy &> /dev/null still shows blank output

Tags: bash, virsh

So I have an annoying problem. I have a script that changes some configuration on a given text file. To change that specific file, I must first destroy the Virtual Machine guest on my KVM. The problem is that every time it stops there is a blank space in the output of the script, as you can see:

```
vfp-8vr Found!
Check if vfp-8vr has stopped ................................. [OK]

Check if vfp-8vr node has changed ............................ [OK]
Check if vfp-8vr has started ................................. [OK]
vfp-9vr Found!
Check if vfp-9vr has stopped ................................. [OK]

Check if vfp-9vr node has changed ............................ [OK]
Check if vfp-9vr has started ................................. [OK]
vfp-10vr Found!
Check if vfp-10vr has stopped ................................. [OK]

Check if vfp-10vr node has changed ............................ [OK]
Check if vfp-10vr has started ................................. [OK]
```

I have included /dev/null to my script as it hides the output, and in theory it works, but there is still a bank space showing up regardless...

```
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
  if [[ -n "$i" ]]
     then
         echo "$i Found!"

         virsh destroy $i &> /dev/null
         echo -e "Check if \e[32m$i\e[0m has stopped ................................. [OK]"

         virsh numatune $i $opt_node0
         echo -e "Check if \e[32m$i\e[0m node has changed ............................ [OK]"

         virsh start $i &> /dev/null
         echo -e "Check if \e[32m$i\e[0m has started ................................. [OK]"

  fi
done
```

Does anyone has any idea of how can I run `virsh destroy` in the background without showing that annoying space in my output?

Disclaimer: I already used `[Command] > /dev/null 2>&1 &` as well, and same thing :/

Comment: Note that the `&` in `&>` does not run the command in the background; it redirects stdout and stderr, as opposed to plain `>` which is only stdout.

Comment: I removed & from &> and left > but it still shows the blank :/

Comment: You're not redirecting output of `virsh numatune`.

Comment: OMG! Siguza! you are right lol! how could I have missed it! It solved the problem adding /dev/null to virsh numatune....

Answer (score 0):

Silly me, I forgot to add /dev/null to the virsh numatune command:

```
Check if vfp-8vr has stopped ................................. [OK]
Check if vfp-8vr node has changed ............................ [OK]
Check if vfp-8vr has started ................................. [OK]
vfp-9vr Found!
Check if vfp-9vr has stopped ................................. [OK]
Check if vfp-9vr node has changed ............................ [OK]
Check if vfp-9vr has started ................................. [OK]
vfp-10vr Found!
Check if vfp-10vr has stopped ................................. [OK]
Check if vfp-10vr node has changed ............................ [OK]
Check if vfp-10vr has started ................................. [OK]
```

Thanks community!